# Generate JWT bearer token from certificate and private key

Tags: c#, .net, rest, jwt

We need to consume a REST webservice, for which we need to supply a JWT bearer token.
We have received a certificate for this purpose, which is placed in a keystore.

The token should be generated based on the key-pair of the keystore and a private key.

How can we generate this bearer token in .NET / C#?

EDIT ............

the decoded token should have the following format:

```
HEADER
{
  "alg": "RS256",
  "typ": "JWT",
  "use": "sig",
  "x5c": [
    "XXXXXXXXXXXX.....
    ]
)
PAYLOAD
{
  "iat": 1533642657,
  "exp": 1549772657,
  "sub": "ABCDE"
}
```

Comment: sorry, edit accepted.

Comment: Have a look at https://jwt.io/, you will certainly find a .NET/C# library that will help you to generate JWT signed/hashed with the key material you have

Comment: I'm using those libraries but can't get the token generated in the expected format...

Comment: What is your expected format? JWT bearer tokens are usually a json object encoded in base64.

Comment: @Logan the expected format is in the question text...

Comment: Yes that's standard JWT structure, but you can't go putting new lines in a bearer token if you are putting it in an http header. That's why I'm asking if you aren't actually looking for a base64 encoded version of your example.

Comment: Here's an easy looking lib: https://github.com/senzacionale/jwt-portable-dotnet

Comment: @Logan The format I supplied is an example token we received, and decoded with the debugger on jwt.io

Comment: I am not sure this kind of question is legit here. As I understand, what you are asking is to help you to use a library to get it working. The answers you will receive will certainly be opinionated.